# What does fit, transform, and fit_transform do in PCA available in sklearn.decomposition?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I am trying to mimic the behavior of `PCA` class available in `sklearn.decomposition`.

I have wrote a method which computes the SVD but I am not sure what does `fit()`, `tranform()`, and `fit_transform()` do without which I'm not able to proceed further.

I think `fit()` computes the svd and the singular values can be accessed using the `singular_values_` attribute but I don't know about the remaining two methods.

Comment: What classes do you inherit from? Only `BaseEstimator` and `TransformerMixin`, or another one?

Comment: I haven't inherited anything. I'm trying to build from scratch using only basic numpy functions.

Comment: If you want to use an estimator or transformer in a sklearn context (in a pipeline, in a gridsearch..) you need to inherit those mixins. [This article](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/data_transforms.html) gives lots of info about how to implement parts of the data pipeline yourself.

Comment: Also, are you aware of sklearn's [TruncatedSVD](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html#sklearn-decomposition-truncatedsvd)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/data_transforms.html) you can see a general explanation of `fit()`, `transform()`, and `fit_transform()`:

> [...] a `fit` method, which learns model parameters (e.g. mean and standard
>   deviation for normalization) from a training set, and a `transform`
>   method which applies this transformation model to unseen data.
>   `fit_transform` may be more convenient and efficient for modelling and
>   transforming the training data simultaneously.